# Statevector from Density matrix of non-pure state

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state, density-matrix, linear-algebra

I have a state vector of a 16 qubit system. I want to get the wave function (in the form of a state vector) for half and quarter of this system. When I try to make a `partial_trace` to obtain the density matrix of a subsystem and represent this matrix as a state vector (by `DensityMatrix.to_statevector()`), I get the error "`QiskitError: 'Density matrix is not a pure state'`". Is it possible to obtain the wave function of a subsystem given the state vector of the system?

Comment: Given a mixed state, there is no unique wave function that can be ascribed to it; the best you can do is a convex combination of wave functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you diagonalize the density matrix, the resulting eigenvectors are pure states of your mixture which gives the density matrix